# Logging isn't writing to file

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, logging

I'm using the following example from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging.html), with Python 3.6.5 from a virtual environment on Gnu/Linux:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

I only get this message in stdout:

```
WARNING:root:And this, too
```

No output file is being produced.

I've noticed that it works fine with Python 2.7.15.

Any ideas?

Comment: I ran the same code in Python 3.6.5 and it seems to be working fine. So something else is causing your problem.

Comment: @sP_ I've added that the test was done within a virtual environment

Comment: I too had tried it in a virtual environment. Are you running the code as it is or do you have anything before or after this? Check if you're running this on `DEBUG` level. If you are, then try changing levels and see if the output makes sense. With the given information I can't think of any way to fix this.

Comment: @sP_ I'm running the code as it is, inside a script. The script doesn't contain anything else. By changing the level from `DEBUG` to `INFO` the same behavior is being produced. Thanks for the feedback.